# Gnu Sed: Space Character class not matching for end of line character

Tags: text-processing, sed, gnu, whitespace

Pattern: abc followed by space or is the last character in a line.

```
orig="abc[[:space:]]+";
new=Hello
sed -i -r -e "s|${orig}|${new}|g" ./file ;
```

File:

```
abc
abcd
abc

abc d
```

After executing:

```
abc
abcd
abc

Hellod
```

Expected Output:

```
Hello
abcd
Hello

Hello d
```

What am I missing?

---

Note: I want to preserve the space character.

Comment: I noticed that you said "Pattern: abc followed by space or is the last character in a line" but then showed `abc d` being translated to `Hellod` when "abc(space)" was *not* the end of line -- `d` is. Which rule is correct? `abc(spaces)` or `abc(spaces)(end of line)`?

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is a *word boundary* anchor? `s/abc\b/Hello/` or (GNU sed) `s/abc\>/Hello/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** what you want is to preserve spaces:

> Note: I want to preserve the space character.

Then, match them, but restore them on the replacement:

```
 orig='abc([[:space:]]+)'
 new='Hello\1'
 sed -E -e "s|${orig}|${new}|g" ./infile ;
```

That will generate this output (to modify in-place add the appropriate `-i` option):

```
 Hello  
 abcd  
 Hello   

 Hello d
```

Of course, that is assuming the file had some spaces at the end of some lines:

```
 $ cat infile | sed -n l
 abc  $
 abcd  $
 abc   $
 $
 abc d$
```

If you also need that the regex match lines that do not end on spaces, you need a more complex regex:

```
 orig='abc([[:space:]]+|$)';
 new='Hello\1';
 sed -E -e "s,${orig},${new},g" ./infile ;
```

Of course, the `s|||` delimiter had to be changed to `s,,,` to avoid conflicts with the `|` required by the regex for alternative.

Comment: Why do we have to add `|$`? According to [sed, a stream editor: Character Classes and Bracket Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html) : Space characters: in the ‘C’ locale, this is tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, and space.

Comment: (1) I tried to match your words: *space or is the last character in a line*. The **only** way to tell a regex to match the end of a line is `$`, no other. The syntax fo an `or` is `|`, so that is what I wrote. **IF** you meant: several spaces or none, the regex would have been `abc([[:space:]]*$)`, no `|` needed, but the *end of line* is still required. (Cont...) @Nikhil

Comment: (2) There is no way to match a newline in grep (BRE, ERE or most pcre without a `-z` option used). That is also said in `info grep`: *Since newline is also a separator for the list of patterns, there is no way to match newline characters in a text.* So, the character range may (in some OSes) match a newline but there is never a newline to match in most grep text (exception noted above with `grep -Pz` or some other corner case uses). @Nikhil

Answer (score 1):

Instead of matching, capturing and then re-inserting the whitespace, just look for "abc" as a *standalone word*. With GNU sed, use `\<` and `\>` as word boundaries:

```
sed 's/\<abc\>/Hello/g' file
```

```
Hello
abcd
Hello

Hello d
```

If you want to put the pattern and replacement into variables, you just have to be careful to quote the backslashes appropriately.

```sh
pattern="\\<abc\\>"    # or: pattern='\<abc\>'
replacement=Hello
sed "s/$pattern/$replacement/" file
```